# Why doesn't Webview display strings other than in English?

Tags: android, webview

I have used the following code to display a string in android Webview:

```
    webView.loadData(anEnglishString + "<br />" + aPersianString, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Also Note that I tried to substitute "**utf-8**" with: "**unicode**", "**utf8**", "**utf-16**", "**ansi**", ... But each time I got the following output in WebView:

> *This message is in English*
> %%#:-=%@+=%-#@##%@%

By the way, I also tried to use:

```
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, ..., null);
```

as well as:

```
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncoding();
```

But I'm still getting the same wired characters for Persian message.

Comment: Is `aPersianString` properly constructed using some persian known encoding? or using `utf-8`

Answer (score 2):

I finally used the following code to solve the problem:

```
    WebView.LoadUrl("data:text/html;charset=UTF-8," + nonEnglishString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also come with the same problem and i fixed that problem.

You should use like this,

```
try {
                // get input stream for text
                InputStream is = getAssets().open("YOUR HTML.html");//index.html
                // check size
                int size = is.available();
                // create buffer for IO
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                // get data to buffer
                is.read(buffer);
                // close stream
                is.close();
                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, new String(buffer),
                        "text/html", "utf-8", null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

> webview.loadData(html_content, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");

I tested it, and it works.